# Future composition in Scala with chunked response

Tags: scala

I think I have understanding of how future composition works but I am confused how to invoke the next future on chunk of response from first future.
Say the first future returns a list of integer and list is huge. I want to apply some function to that list with 2 elements at a time. How do I do that?

This example summarizes my dilemma:

```
val a = Future(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))
def f(a: List[Int]) = Future(a map (_ + 2))
val res = for {
 list <- a
 chunked <- list.grouped(2).toList
} yield f(chunked)

<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]]]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
        chunked <- list.grouped(2).toList
            ^
```

The return type has to be Future[?] so I can fix it by moving second future to yield part:

```
val res = for {
  list <- a
} yield {
  val temp = for {
    chunked <- list.grouped(2).toList
  } yield f(chunked)
  Future.sequence(temp)
}
```

I feel it loses its elegance now, since it becomes nested (see two for comprehensions instead of one in the first approach). Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
a.map { _.grouped(2).toList }.flatMap { Future.traverse(_)(f) }
```

Or, if you are set on only using `for` comprehension for some reason, here is how, without "cheating" :)

```
for {
  b <- a
  c <- Future.traverse(b.grouped(2).toList)(f)
} yield c
```

*Edit in response to the comment* It's not really that hard to add more processing to your chunked list if needed:

```
for {
   b <- a
   chunks = b.grouped(2).toList
   processedChunks = processChunks(chunks)
   c <- Future.traverse(processedChunks)
} yield c
```

Or, without `for` comprehension:

```
a
.map { _.grouped(2).toList }
.map(processChunks)
.flatMap { Future.traverse(_)(f) }
```

Comment: Thanks this solution works! However I think, it becomes incredibly difficult to extend this solution. Like if I want to process the chunked list further and then apply `f` it makes it hard here :(

Comment: Well, the more you want to "extend" stuff, the more difficult it becomes generally ... that's why programmers earn the big bucks. :) 
I mean, it's not surprising that doing more processing is more difficult then doing less processing, is it? 
I edited the answer to demonstrate the general idea how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix `Future` with `List` in a for-comprehension. All involved objects have to be of the same type. Also, in your working example, your result value `res` is of type `Future[Future[List[List[Int]]]]`, which is probably not what you want.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
a: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3bd3cdc8
f: (a: List[Int])scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]]

scala> val b: Future[List[List[Int]]] = a.map(list => list.grouped(2).toList)
b: scala.concurrent.Future[List[List[Int]]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@74db196c

scala> val res: Future[List[List[Int]]] = b.flatMap(lists => Future.sequence(lists.map(f)))
res: scala.concurrent.Future[List[List[Int]]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@28f9873c
```

With for-comprehension

```
for {
    b ← a.map(list ⇒ list.grouped( 2 ).toList)
    res ← Future.sequence(b.map(f))
} yield res
```

Comment: when you say `All involved objects have to be of the same type` it essentially means for `a <- b` kind of operation `b` return type must be Future[?]. Also you use map inside for comprehension its cheating :D (since it is a new for-comprehension essentially)

Comment: You could as well remove the `map` and add a new line below `c <- Future.successful(b.grouped(2).toList)`.